# facebook social sign-in statistics

Tags: facebook, statistics

I am wanting to find out how many people per any time period sign in on other websites using the facebook social sign-in buttons, but i am having no luck finding any statistics or demographics, can anyone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

That depends upon user base. I am using social login provided by LoginRadius and their social login analytics helped me in understanding the behaviour. As i am providing multiple ID provider selection option, i have seen still more than 60% users prefering facebook with google coming second. I have seen peek of 600 users logging in my website using facebook. Hope this helps! Really thankful of social analytics by LoginRadius

Answer (score 0):

That depends upon user base. I am using social login provided by LoginRadius and their social login analytics helped me in understanding the behaviour. As i am providing multiple ID provider selection option, i have seen still more than 60% users prefering facebook with google coming second. I have seen peek of 600 users logging in my website using facebook. Hope this helps! Really thankful of social analytics by LoginRadius